# How do I retrieve embedding vector from FAISS database by index number?

Tags: python, chatbot, openai-api, chatgpt-api, faiss

I've chunked and embedded N number of documents into an FAISS database db. How do I retrieve the embeddings corresponding to document x out of N documents embeddeded into FAISS database, in python?

I can't seem to find any associated methods for doing this simple task.